# Covert numerical values in a column in one dataset to corresponding text values on a different dataset

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, left-join

I have two datasets, one has all numeric, while the other has the conversion:

This is an example of the live dataset, it has more than 2 column, but in this instance 191 is USA
[image: Example of Datset]

This is an example of the conversion dataset. Note that sometimes the lengths of the columns are different. For instance, country has 200 elements, while Ethnicity has 6.

[image: Example of Conversion dataset]

How can I write code that will change the value in countryofbirth to US - 191 transformed to USA? The original dataset is called my_data, while the conversion dataset is called Coversion.

```
I have tried left_joins, 
my_data <- left_join(my_data, select(Conversion, c("StateGrewUpIn", "State")), by = "StateGrewUpIn")

I have tried merge:
    my_data <- merge(x = my_data, y = Conversion[ , c("StateGrewUpIn", "State")], by = "StateGrewUpIn", all.x=TRUE)
```

Nothing seems to work, it always duplicates the rows beyond the maximum in the original dataset. In other words, rather than just doing a clean vlookup, it is duplicating rows, or including rows from the Conversion dataset.

```
Conversion Dataset
> str(Conversion)
'data.frame':   200 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ Religion                : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 NA NA ...
 $ Rel                     : chr  "Protestant" "Catholic" "Islam" "Judaism" ...
 $ PoliticalView           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 NA NA NA ...
 $ Political_views         : chr  "Very Progressive/Left-wing" "Progressive/Left-wing" "Somewhat Progressive/Left-wing" "Moderate/Centrist" ...
 $ CountryofBirth          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Country                 : chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Andorra" ...
 $ Citizenship             : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Citizen                 : chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Andorra" ...
 $ StateGrewUpIn           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ State                   : chr  "Alaska (AK)" "American Samoa (AS)" "Arizona (AZ)" "Arkansas (AR)" ...
 $ Ethnicity               : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Ethnic                  : chr  "White" "Asian" "Latino" "Black" ...
 $ Education               : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Education_level         : chr  "Some high school/secondary school" "High school degree/completed secondary school" "Some university" "University degree" ...
 $ YearlyIncome            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 NA NA NA ...
 $ Income                  : chr  "Less than $10,000 USD a year" "USD $10,000-$20,000" "USD $20,000-$40,000" "USD USD $40,000-$60,000" ...
 $ HighestEducationPar     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Parent_Highest_Education: chr  "Some high school/secondary school" "High school degree/completed secondary school" "Some university" "University degree" ...
 $ Atten_check_ans_1       : int  1 2 3 4 5 NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Attention_Check         : chr  "strongly disagree" "moderately disagree" "neither disagree nor agree" "moderately agree" ...



Example of large dataset (note it has >200 columns so I just took the mentioned example above).
> str(my_data)
'data.frame':   35 obs. of  228 variables:
 $ Citizenship                     : chr  "144" "191" "191" "191" ...
 $ CountryofBirth                  : chr  "144" "191" "191" "191" ...
 $ StartDate                       : chr  "2019-05-17 13:49:35" "2019-05-17 12:54:30" "2019-05-17 12:54:40" "2019-05-17 12:54:20" ...
 $ EndDate                         : chr  "2019-05-17 14:00:12" "2019-05-17 13:00:21" "2019-05-17 13:02:02" "2019-05-17 13:04:25" ...
 $ Status                          : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
```

Comment: Can you post some data? Use `dput()` or something else.

Comment: I did not understand your goal.

Comment: As @william3031 mentioned, some sample data would help. This article can show you how:
https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html

Comment: `left_join` needs two tables as input, btw.

Comment: @yake84 I installed the package, loaded it with library, however once I copy the data and try and paste as tibble, I just get: Could not paste clipboard as tibble. Text could not be parsed as table.

Comment: @bbiasi My main dataset has all numbers (191), while my Conversion dataset, has the values which are meaningful categories in text form (USA). I am looking to overwrite the columns in my main dataset (191) with the corresponding values in my Conversion dataset (USA). In the conversion dataset, if you found 191 in the Citizenship column, you would find USA in the associated row of the Citizen column. I need to do this. It is essentially a vlookup - left join where 1 column is retrieved.

Comment: Did you try copying from excel? It doesn't work if you try to copy from the console output or from the viewer.

Comment: @yake84 indeed it was from Excel

Comment: Bummer. Can you mock something up for us, use `dput()`, or use one of the built in datasets to replicate the issue? `iris`, `mpg` and `diamonds` are good for demos.

Comment: So it is NAs in the values that are causing the problems, since country has the max length in the Conversion dataframe of 200 it is good. But other smaller columns are causing the problem...

Comment: Looks like you found the issue. If you need further help please use `dput()` and paste that wild looking thing that prints out in your code example. `df <- structure(list(...))`.  I see you added `str()` and it helps us see what the data looks like but doesn't let us replicate it on our computers.

Comment: Useful tool for importing data quickly from Excel: `install.packages("datapasta")`

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Please clarify via edits, not comments.